# Run react native es6 javascript through babel

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs

What's the easiest way to run a javascript module that exists in my react native source tree using babel?

Let's say I have the following file

```
// hi.js
import _ from 'lodash'    
console.log(_.upperCase('hi'));
```

And I want to just run this quickly from the command line to test it out or use it in a utility script or something like that. I can't use node directly because of the import statement. I know I can install and configure babel... but since babel is already bundled and configured with RN can I just use that somehow?

e.g > workspace/node_modules/babe-core/bin/babel-node hi.js

Can I just install babel-cli into the project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can compile a file using the babel command line:

```
babel hi.js --out-file hi-compiled.js --plugins=es2015,react
```

This will allow you to then run the file with node:

```
node hi-compiled.js
```

---

Alternatively you could use babel-node which would do it in one command:

```
babel-node hi.js --plugins es2015
```

---

All this can be achieved with `npm install -g babel-cli`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yep that's sort of the standard way of using babel.

But since babel is already provided (and configured) as part of RN I'd like to just use the one bundled in the react native node modules.

I guess that doesn't really matter though. Just curious if it was possible.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. I see now you already were thinking of babel-node. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want a project specific command? I don't know of a react-native way of doing that but you could achieve that with npm. For example you could create a script in your package.json: `"scripts": { "babel-node": "babel-node"}` then run `npm run babel-node -- path/to/hi.js`